# However intelligent (you may be/you are?), you cannot succeed without hard work

Tags: exam-questions

This is an sentence improvement question from an exercise with the bold part to be improved from  the given options. The actual sentence given is

> However intelligent **you may be,** you cannot succeed without hard work.

Among the given options **you are** is an option. Does using *you are* in place of *you may be* makes any difference in the sentence ? Is it any how better ?

Comment: What are the other options?

Comment: @SovereignSun  A) you are B) you should be C) you could be D) you might be E) no correction required.

Comment: Well, the correct answer is E) - **you may be** is well placed and *no correction required*